# Develope and Configuring the Views and the Controller

Tags: java, spring

can you help me to fix a problem.

```
@Controller
public class JobController {

    @Autowired
    private JobService jobService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView jobListPage() {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
        List<Job> jobList = jobService.findAllJobs();
        mav.addObject("jobList", jobList);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do,

```
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        List<Job> jobList = jobService.findAllJobs();
        modelAndView.addObject("jobList", jobList);
        return modelAndView;
```

Comment: @maria let me know if you need more info